# SQLZoo Nobel Quiz #3—What's the difference between these statements?

Tags: sql

https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Nobel_Quiz

The table in question is displayed at the top of the page.

Two answer choices for Question 3, "Pick the code that shows the amount of years where no Medicine awards were given," are as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT yr) FROM nobel
WHERE yr IN (SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject <> 'Medicine')
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT yr) FROM nobel
WHERE yr NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Medicine')
```

SQLZoo only takes the second option as a correct answer, but, to me, these answers look like they'd return the same results. Could someone give some insight as to why the first option is incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: Because they don't return the same results. The first would include years where a prize was given in both medicine and something else, where the second would eliminate that year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first answers the question:

> How many years had a Nobel prize in a field other than medicine?

The second attempts to answer:

> How many years did not have a Nobel price in medicine?

These are different questions and would normally have two different answers.

There are other important differences.  The second query returns no rows if any value of `yr` is NULL on a medicine prize (that is why I say "attempts to answer").  `NULL` values have no such global effect on the first query.

The set-based logic that SQL is based on *is* legitimate logic.  But it requires a bit more thought than handling basic boolean expressions.